# perl has problem if filenames contain dashes

Tags: regular-expression, perl

```
... | perl -pe "s/([^$filespec]*)($filespec)/ ...
```

So I have a function where the above construction works fine if `$filespec` is most things. However *if there's a dash in the file name* I get an `Invalid [] range` message.

How can I ensure that the variable `$filespec` expands to a file name that is protected from this sort of parsing error?

Comment: As an RE that seems to make very little sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key assumption -- `$filespec` is just a set of characters you want to match. It is *not* a regular expression.

Lets simulate the issue with some code

```
filespec = 'z-a'
perl -e 'print "MATCH\n" if "DEF" =~ /$filespec/'
```

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filespec = 'z-a';

print "Match\n" if "DEF" =~ m/[^$filespec]/ ;
```

Running that gives

```
Invalid [] range "z-a" in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/[^z-a <-- HERE ]/ at try line 6.
```

The issue is triggered when `$filespec` is expanded in your regular expression to `m/[^z-a]/`. In this instance `z-a` is an invalid character range.

To fix you need to escape (at least) the `-` in `$filespec`. Using `quotemeta` should make the problem go away, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filespec = quotemeta 'z-a';

print "Match\n" if "DEF" =~ m/[^$filespec]/ ;
```

output is

```
Match
```

Including this into a simulation of your pipeline command. First the failing command version

```
filespec='z-a'
perl -e "print qq[MATCH\n] if 'DEF' =~ /[^$filespec]/"
```

running gives

```
Invalid [] range "z-a" in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/[^z-a <-- HERE ]/ at -e line 1.
```

and here is the fixed version

```
filespec='z-a'; 
filespec=`perl -e "print quotemeta qq[$filespec]"`
perl -e "print qq[MATCH\n] if 'DEF' =~ /[^$filespec]/"
```

Comment: Interesting, but i can find no command named quotemeta.  Where do I find it?

Comment: `quotemeta` is a Perl built-in function. Updated the answer to show how to integrate into you shell commands

Comment: Thanks.  The edited version is a good example of a really helpful answer to a question.

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta

Comment: @pmqs should the 'fixed' version at the bottom actually declare `filespec='a-z';` instead of `filespec='z-a';` ?

Comment: @jubilatious1 No, the fixed version doesn't mean that the character range should now work - the only reason for the `z-a` range is to trigger a regex error for illustration purposes. The `quotemeta` will convert the unexpected character range,  `z-a`,  into `z\-a`, so a literal `z`, an escaped `-` and a literal `z`

Answer (score 1):

A dash in a bracket expression is treated as a range unless it is either escaped with a backslash<sup>1</sup> or is the first or last character in the expression (or, if the expression is negated with `^` either the first char after `^` or the last char).

e.g.

`[a-z]` matches all lowercase characters from `a` to `z` <sup>(but see note 2)</sup>

`[a\-z]`, `[-az]`, and `[az-]` all match only 3 characters: `-`, `a`, and `z`.

And, as @pmqs points out in their answer, `[z-a]` is an invalid range and will generate an error.

If your regular expression contains a bracket expression with one or more dashes, then you'll need to modify it so that it works as you intend.  As with most things, it's up to you to understand the software and language features you are using well enough to make them do what you want/expect.

See `man perlre` for details about perl regular expressions, including convenience features and other "gotchas" that you need to be aware of.  There's a lot in that man page, you won't master it all at once.  Refer back to it when you need to, you will be learning more about how it works for years to come.  See also `man perlrequick` for a quick reference and `man perlretut` for a tutorial.  And `man perlrecharclass` for more about character classes & bracket expressions in perl.  And `man perlrebackslash` for more about backslashes and escape sequences in perl.

(If your linux distro or unix doesn't have perl documentation available as `man` pages, then use `perldoc` as the command to run instead of `man`, e.g. `perldoc perlre`).

Given that perl has five main man pages totalling about 54000 words of prose and examples dedicated just to regular expressions (and two more which you'll probably never need: `perlreguts` describing how the perl regex engine works and `perlreapi` describing perlre's plugin interface), you might be beginning to guess that it's a complex topic - and you'd be right about that.

---

Notes:

<sup>1</sup> not all regex engines support escaping characters inside a bracket expression.  Perl does, most don't - e.g. GNU grep's BRE (default, or `-G`) and ERE (`-E`) don't, but GNU grep's perl-compatible (`-P`) regexes do.

<sup>2</sup> `[[:alpha:]]`, `[[:upper:]]` or `[[:lower:]]` are usually better for matching alphabetic characters as they can work with unicode text as well as just plain ASCII. As does `[[:alnum:]]` for alphanumeric chars.

Comment: "you will be learning more about how it works for years to come"

Yes, and for the  moment I just want it fixed, quick and dirty.  I'll  become a perl expert when I have a few years to spend on that.

Comment: yeah, and i told you what the problem was and how to fix it.  then told you how to learn more to help you avoid mistakes in future - with perl regular expressions, at least.  There's more to learning perl itself...or any language.  You don't need to become an expert, but you do need to learn enough to understand what you're doing. Otherwise you'll keep on making mistakes like this and never know why or how to fix them.